# json_extract_path_text does not unescape string values?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

When I run this query in Redshift, I would expect `json_extract_path_text` to remove the backslash from the `"\"b\""` value:

```sql
select j, json_extract_path_text(j, 'a', true) as a
from (select '{"a": "\\"b\\""}' as j);
```

Instead, it appears that the string value is extracted verbatim, and the results look like this:

```
{"a": "\"b\""}
\"b\"
```

Is this intentional? If yes, what would be the idiomatic way to remove the backslashes?