# json_extract_array_element_text does not unescape string values?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

Similarly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71995798/json-extract-path-text-does-not-unescape-string-values) about `json_extract_path_text`, when I run this query in Redshift, I would expect `json_extract_array_element_text` to remove the backslashes from the `"\"b\""` value:

```sql
select
    j, 
    json_extract_array_element_text(j, 0) as a
from (select '["\\"b\\""]' as j);
```

Instead, it appears that the string value is extracted verbatim, and the results look like this:

```
["\"b\""]
\"b\"
```

Is this intentional? If yes, what would be the idiomatic way to remove the backslashes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL unescape JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414361/postgresql-unescape-json-string)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the reported "problem" is that string escaping and parsing of literals is working exactly as expected.

Comment: @MikeOrganek The literal parsing does work, the literal `'["\\"b\\""]'` is parsed as the string `["\"b\""]`. But a JSON parser should parse that as an array with a single element, the string `"b"`, not as an array containing the string `\"b\"`. There is nothing in the `json_extract_array_element_text` (or `json_extract_path_text`, for that matter) to suggest that they are not following the JSON standard.

Comment: For clarification, I would expect the second line of the output to be
`"b"` not `\"b\"`

Comment: The output should be a length 3 string, not a length 5 string. Compare Javascript `JSON.parse('["\\"b\\""]')[0].length` (gives 3) and Redshift `select length(json_extract_array_element_text('["\\"b\\""]', 0))` (gives 5)

Comment: Or even Redshift's own `json_parse`: `select length(p[0]::varchar) from (select json_parse('["\\"b\\""]') as p)` (gives 3)